# Go-generated animated GIFs didn't work in windows

Tags: image, file, go, gif

I found an example didn't work properly in Windows.
This program demonstrates basic usage of Go's standard image packages, which we'll use to create a sequence of bit-mapped images and then encode the sequence as a GIF animation.

```
package main

import (
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "image/gif"
    "io"
    "math"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
)

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

//!+main

var palette = []color.Color{color.White, color.Black}

const (
    whiteIndex = 0 // first color in palette
    blackIndex = 1 // next color in palette
)

func main() {
    //!-main
    // The sequence of images is deterministic unless we seed
    // the pseudo-random number generator using the current time.
    // Thanks to Randall McPherson for pointing out the omission.
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())

    if len(os.Args) > 1 && os.Args[1] == "web" {
        //!+http
        handler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            lissajous(w)
        }
        http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
        //!-http
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8000", nil))
        return
    }
    //!+main
    lissajous(os.Stdout)
}

func lissajous(out io.Writer) {
    const (
        cycles  = 5     // number of complete x oscillator revolutions
        res     = 0.001 // angular resolution
        size    = 100   // image canvas covers [-size..+size]
        nframes = 64    // number of animation frames
        delay   = 8     // delay between frames in 10ms units
    )
    freq := rand.Float64() * 3.0 // relative frequency of y oscillator
    anim := gif.GIF{LoopCount: nframes}
    phase := 0.0 // phase difference
    for i := 0; i < nframes; i++ {
        rect := image.Rect(0, 0, 2*size+1, 2*size+1)
        img := image.NewPaletted(rect, palette)
        for t := 0.0; t < cycles*2*math.Pi; t += res {
            x := math.Sin(t)
            y := math.Sin(t*freq + phase)
            img.SetColorIndex(size+int(x*size+0.5), size+int(y*size+0.5),
                blackIndex)
        }
        phase += 0.1
        anim.Delay = append(anim.Delay, delay)
        anim.Image = append(anim.Image, img)
    }
    gif.EncodeAll(out, &anim) // NOTE: ignoring encoding errors
}
```

The code runs properly in cmd, however, if I run it in Windows Power Shell like:

```
.\lissajous.exe >out.gif
```

The out.gif can't be opened and I don't know why.

Comment: "The out.gif can't be open[ed]" is not a problem description.

Comment: What do you mean it can't be opened? How are you trying to open it? What error message, or other output do you see?

Comment: Don't ignore errors, especially if you have a problem!

Comment: If I try to open the outfile out.gif by Windows default program, it gives me a tip:Can't open this file. Maybe the system think out.gif is not a valid gif file.

Comment: Thanks to the answer bellow, redirecting in cmd.exe instead in powershell, which is the default terminal in vscode, solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GIF file (the gif data) is a binary format, not textual. Attempting to write it to the standard output and redirecting that to a file may suffer transformations. For example, the Windows PowerShell most likely converts some control characters (like `"\n"` to `"\r\n"`), so the resulting binary will not be identical to what [`gif.EncodeAll()`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/gif/#EncodeAll) writes to the standard output. Apparently `cmd.exe` does not do such transformations.

I recommend writing to a file directly (you may pass an [`os.File`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) as the output), or an in-memory buffer which you can dump to a file using [`ioutil.WriteFile()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#WriteFile).

Here's how writing directly to a file could look like:

```
f, err := os.Create("a.gif")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer f.Close()
lissajous(f)
```

Here's how the in-memory solution could look like:

```
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
lissajous(buf)
if err := ioutil.WriteFile("a.gif", buf.Bytes(), 0666); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

See related issue: [image/gif: result of EncodeAll not viewable in Eye of GNOME](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13746)

There is still a chance the result won't be readable by some apps (see above issue), which can be fixed by converting the output image in unix with the following command:

```
convert original.gif -coalesce unoptimized.gif
```

Source: [Fix animated GIF images which eog can't open, but Firefox and ImageMagick can](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887187/fix-animated-gif-images-which-eog-cant-open-but-firefox-and-imagemagick-can)

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell 7.4 support PSNativeCommandPreserveBytePipe.
This issue will be resolved
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/experimental-features?view=powershell-7.3#psnativecommandpreservebytepipe)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The problem is clear enough that you will have to wait for future powershell updates.